# Relationship of routers to networks

Tags: networking, router, lan, subnet

I was wondering, in networking, what is the relationship of routers to networks?

Can the same router be the gateway for 2+ networks? For example, if I have a wireless router at home, can I configure it to "host" 2 home distinct LANs from it? What about subnets? Can the same router "host" 2+ subnets of the same parent network?

Comment: What have you found so far? The answer is yes, but not on all hardware...

Comment: Thanks @BigChris (+1) - but this is a chicken-and-egg problem, I'm not even sure what to ask/search for. Would this be considered "multi tenant" routers? "multiple network routers", something else?!?

Comment: Look for routers capable of VLANing... You can do it many different ways but all depend on your hardware, knowledge, security requirements and wallet size. Some routers offer it out of the box (DrayTek Vigor range, for example), some can be "flashed" to alternative firmwares (such as some Netgear routers) such as DD-WRT or Tomato. More expensive solutions can be dedicated PCs with multiple NICs and an OS like Linux acting as the router or dedicated appliances.

Comment: A router capable of VLANing can use the individual sockets at the back (LAN 1-4) as separate networks each with their own DHCP, subnets etc. and you can then create ACLs to allow traffic between the networks if necessary.

Comment: What if the router has just aliases and not VLANs, like AP-Router NG has? I've never tried it, just tossing in my 2 cents, since it's related. [here's what I mean](http://komprogram.pl/aprouter.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

When a device tries to send a packet to another network (outside its subnet), it will send the packet to the router, so the router can forward the packet as needed (this is a simplification).

Some routers can listen on multiple IP addresses on multiple subnets (usually one IP per subnet). when a device sends a packet to the router, the router will then forward the packet to either the other local network, or your internet (WAN) connection (assuming a 'home' set up).

Of course, there are multiple ways to set this up, with the simplest being a separate subnet on each ethernet port. As mentioned by others, not all routers will do this; I believe DD-WRT and Tomato has these features, and personally I have a MikroTik router at home which works well with a similar set up. However, without providing a router make/model, we wont be able to give you instructions.